# Give the infimum of the image of a function defined over a weird real set.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis

If I got a real function f defined over the closed interval $[2,6]$ as

$\begin{eqnarray}f(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{lr} 5   &x=2 \\9-x^2 &2<x<6 \\   3 &x=6\end{array} \right.\end{eqnarray}$

I got stuck since I think of $\inf\{f(x): x \in [2,6]\}$ as a number $f(x)$ where $x$ is a number in $[2,6]$ close enough to $6$ by the left but is never $6$ since $f(6)=2$ and $2$ is clearly not $\inf\{f(x): x\in [2,6]\}$. So how can I properly understand, write and express $\inf\{f(x): x\in [2,6]\}$? Since this is a calculus problem so keeping the expression simple would be more useful than extra sophisticated analysis expression because the original problem only ask me for giving $\inf\{f(x): x\in [2,6]\}$. Thanks, and sorry  for grammatical-spelling errors.

Comment: Thanks for learning Mathjax!

Answer (score 0):

Its infimum is -27. There isn't a minimum.

Comment: Brevity of the answer is often a virtue, but this occasion seems to call for something extra. So could you elaborate a bit? You probably know this well, but from the look of things, the asker is in need of understanding as opposed to just an answer. Your answer has been flagged for low quality. My interpretation (as a moderator) is that as a new user you were simply somewhat unfamiliar with the local norms.